# How to do in-app purchase in ios5?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, xcode4.3, ios5

I have used the following code for in-app purchase.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    NSLog(@"Can Buy Product");

    SKProductsRequest *productRequest=[[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.mycompany.myproduct.productpack"]];
    productRequest.delegate=self;
    [productRequest start];
}
else {

    NSLog(@"Product Can't be purchased");
}
}

-(IBAction)purchasePack1 {

SKPayment *payment=[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.myproduct.productpack"];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

validProduct=nil;
int count=[response.products count];
if (count>0) {
    NSLog(@"Product Avail");

    validProduct=[response.products objectAtIndex:0];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No Product avail");
    [purchaseBtn setHidden:TRUE];
}
}


-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"Purchasing");   
            [activityIndicatorObj setHidden:FALSE];
            [activityIndicatorObj startAnimating];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"Thanks For Purchasing " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alt show];
            [alt release];
            NSLog(@"Purchased");
            [activityIndicatorObj stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicatorObj setHidden:TRUE];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            if (transaction.error.code!=SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            UIAlertView *alt1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Some Error Encountered!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alt1 show];
                [alt1 release];
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            [activityIndicatorObj stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicatorObj setHidden:TRUE];
            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Restored");
            [activityIndicatorObj stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicatorObj setHidden:TRUE];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;



        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

When i click purchase Button i am getting an alert message saying "You have already purchased this product and hasn't downloaded yet, Do you want to download.?"
When i click yes i didn't get any response from App, and i am sure that product hasn't downloaded. Can anyone please tell me the suggestion for this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does it print the "Product avail" text when you load the view?

Comment: paymentWithProductIdentifier: is deprecated since iOS 5. You should use paymentWithProduct: instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any implementation of the `- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId` - did you miss that part? In any case you should receive a notification when the transactionState witch to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased too.

You might want to take a look to Ray Wenderlich tut on [in-app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) purchase if you haven't already it will help you to put in place an in-app manager class. I think you have put the in-app logic in your view controller - it would be good to leave that part in a separate class. So an in-app manager/helper :-)